# How to standardize tick marks when using facet_wrap

Tags: r

Using the Carseats dataset from ISLR I want to plot all other variables against "Sales" in one graph.  To do this I have used tidyr which has worked out well so far except that the x axis are unreadable in the graph because there are too many tick marks.  Is there a way to standardize how many tick marks are in each graph or make some separation so it is readable?

```
library(ISLR)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Carseats %>%
  gather(-Sales, key="var", value="value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value, y=Sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~var, scales="free_x") +
  theme_bw()
```

I just want the x axis to be readable.

Answer (score 1):

ggplot's facet options were designed with the goal of showing various subsets of one data set with common mapping across facets. So your request is a useful EDA task, but not really what ggplot was designed to accommodate easily. The challenge is that not only are the x-axes here across different ranges between facets (no prob), the x-axes are a mix of categorical and continuous variables (eep!).

I'd suggest making two plots, one with the categorical x-axes, like ShelveLoc, Urban, and US, and a separate one for the continuous x-axes. You could then use `cowplot` or `patchwork` to combine them into one plot object, if necessary.

Plots with continuous x-axes:

```
Carseats %>%
  select(-c("ShelveLoc", "Urban", "US")) %>%
  gather(-Sales, key="var", value="value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value, y=Sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~var, scales="free_x", shrink = T) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Plots with categorical x-axes:

```
Carseats %>%
  select(c("Sales", "ShelveLoc", "Urban", "US")) %>%
  gather(-Sales, key="var", value="value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value, y=Sales)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~var, scales="free_x", shrink = T) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I had planned to put them all in one graph, but this works great!  Thanks Jon!